# Why doesn't R add the title at the top of the page?

Tags: r, title

I'm trying to add a title at the top of the page scatterplots, however whenever I use the command *title* it doesn't add the title at the top of page and overwrites my plots. Is there a way to fix this ?

```
plot(median, pch = ".")
title(main = "Scatterplot of the median vectors ",line = 0,font=2)
```

Comment: you can get your code to format better in these posts by putting at least 4 spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: or just by clicking on the 'Code Sample' button in the edit box.

Answer (score 6):

Did you look at the `mtext()` command?  Did you look at the `par(oma=c(...))` option?  Try something like

```
oldpar <- par(oma=c(0,0,2,0), mar=c(3,3,3,1), mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(cumsum(rnorm(1:100)), main="First plot", type='l')
plot(cumsum(rnorm(1:100)), main="Second plot", type='l')
mtext("Overall title", outer=TRUE, cex=1.5)
par(oldpar)
```

Comment: hey this method works well , Im quite curious what do the parameters oma , mar and mfrow stand for ?

Comment: They set, respectively, the outer margin (2 lines at the top) and plot margin (3 at bottom, left and top, 1 at right) and the one row, two columns layout.  But you really want to look at help(par), and as it is a pretty long help page, maybe an introductory book like Dalgaard's as par() is a very useful function to know.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason your code should not work as is.  It works for me just fine.  Are you attempting to do something more than the example code you gave?

Is there a reason not to just use `plot(median, pch = ".", main = "Foo")`?

Comment: somehow this code works much better ,looks like I got alot to learn haha