# Why doesn't the title from R's command mtext() get plotted?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to print an outer title in a plot containing four density graphs.

To exemplify what I am doing, here's some code.

```
 mt = as.data.frame(matrix(data = rnorm(n = 400), ncol = 4))
 par(mfrow = c(2,2))
 plot(density(mt$V1))
 plot(density(mt$V2))
 plot(density(mt$V3))
 plot(density(mt$V4))
 mtext(text = "Test", outer = T, side = 3)
```

I have toyed with the **mtext()** command for a while, changing its position in the code, and adding other parameters to the function. But, in a nutshell, all I am trying to get should be accomplished with the parameters *outer* and *cex*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041893/mtext-smaller-labels-description-when-layout-is-used?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hey, Denis, thanks for your input. I have taken a look at questions regarding mtext before posting mine and the one in the link is one of them. I appreciate your help, but not only did I not find the answer I was looking for in the link you sent, I also still don't know why my code isn't working. It seems a fairly simple piece of code that should work fine. Any ideas why it's not working? Thanks once again.

Comment: I think I've answered this before (I'll go looking for the dupe), but: try `par(mfrow = c(2,2),oma=c(0,0,5,0))`

Comment: almost (not quite) identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656026/why-doesnt-r-add-the-title-at-the-top-of-the-page/1656204#1656204

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I hadn't found the link you sent before. I'm surprised, though. I've used mtext() before and I don't recall ever using the parameter **oma**. Thanks a lot.